# Webpart with update panel is deleting the text in IE's tab on every request

Tags: visual-web-part, ajax

I have a web part that display information to the user.  It lives in the pages: /Pages/default.aspx

The web part was working fine until I wrapped the grid in an update panel.  Now when you sort or filter the grid the title of the page is getting wiped in IE's tab.

So when my grid makes a request, it's an ajax request and it clears out the title of the page in IE and the title of the tab that the page is hosted in.

Any idea why this is happening?

Thanks!

Comment: It was an issue with our custom master page.  Once we removed the masterpage it worked as expected.

Thanks,

Comment: Hi Dan, please write change comment to answer, so it can be marked as answered :-)